# How to use pointer to pointer for passing matrix?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, matrix

Passing matrix as a pointer to pointer to function not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printMatrix(int **matrix, int row, int col)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\r\n");
    }
}
void printM (size_t row, size_t col, int matrix[3][4])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\r\n");
    }
}
int main() 
{
    int M[3][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            M[i][j] = 4*i+j;

    printM(3, 4, M);

    int *row = *M;
    printMatrix(&row, 3, 4);    //not working
}
```

Function `printM` works, but I would like to know how to use pointer to pointer correctly, thanks for help.

Comment: This question gets asked nearly every day. Anyway, you can't pass a double pointer to a 2d-array parameter. You must use one or the other. Or better yet, an STL data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thank-you for this question.  It is a good review of how C does multi-dimensional arrays.  Also, it is OK to do double pointers.  Remember an array reference is equivalent to a pointer, such as: `a[0]` and `*a` both refer to the first element of `int a[12];` where `*a` is the de-referencing of pointer `a`.  And so, `&M` is a the address of the pointer `M` when M is declared as `int M[3][4];`

I modified your code by adding a few comments for clarity and so that it would run in Eclipse using a C compiler from Microsoft, specifically, int declarations where moved out of the for statements.  Other than that it is the same as what you originally wrote with a change to the printMatrix declaration and how it is invoked.

Hope this helps, please ask if more questions...

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void printMatrix(int (*matrix)[3][4], int row, int col)
    {
    int i, j;

    // point t so that when de-referenced it is at
    // the matrices first element
        int *t = (*matrix)[0];

    printf("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
         // in C matrices are stored in Row Major form, so
         // per K&R just sequentially loop thru (*t)[12]
         for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {printf("%d ", *t++);}

         printf("\r\n");

        }
     } // end printMatrix

     void printM (size_t row, size_t col, int matrix[3][4])
     {
     int i, j;

     printf("\n");
         for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
         {
           for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);}

         // new line for next row
         printf("\r\n");
         }
      } 

    int main()
    {
      int i,j;

      // define a matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns
          int M[3][4];

          // fill-in the matrix with values
         for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
              M[i][j] = 4*i + j;

         // print the three rows and four columns of M
         printM(3, 4, M);

         printMatrix(&M, 3, 4);    // Also Works

     }  // end main
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void printMatrix(int *matrix, int row, int col)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("%d ", *(matrix+(i*col)+j);
        printf("\r\n");
    }
}
```

Don't do a double pointer.